# Ember.js error when saving one-to-many relationship model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have problem creating record on one-to-many relationship. I use Ember 1.7 with Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.10.

**`app/models/transaction.js`**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Transaction = DS.Model.extend({
  code: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date', {
    defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }
  }),
  customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', { embedded: 'always', async: true }),
  details: DS.hasMany('transactiondetail', { embedded: 'always', async: true }),
  is_cash_payment: DS.attr('boolean')
});

export default Transaction;
```

**`app/models/transactiondetail.js`**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var TransactionDetail = DS.Model.extend({
  item: DS.belongsTo('item', { embedded: 'always', async: true }),
  max_returned_at: DS.attr('date'),
  returned_at: DS.attr('date'),
  price: DS.attr('number')
});

export default TransactionDetail;
```

**`app/serializers/transaction.js`**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    customer: { serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'id' },
    details: { serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'ids' }
  }
});
```

**`app/serializers/transactiondetail.js`**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
     item: { serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'id' },
  }
});
```

**`app/controllers/transaction/create.js`**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(, {
  needs: ['transactions'],

  transactionCode: '',
  dateNow: new Date(),
  maxReturnedAt: maxReturnedAt,
  selectedItem: [],
  selectedCustomer: null,
  totalPrice: totalPrice,
  payValue: 0,
  change: 0,
  isCashPayment: true,

  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var self = this;

      var record = this.store.createRecord('transaction', {
          code: this.get('transactionCode'),
          customer: this.get('selectedCustomer'),
          is_cash_payment: this.get('isCashPayment')
      });

      this.get('selectedItem').forEach(function( item ) {
        var transactionDetail = self.store.createRecord('transactiondetail', {
          item: item,
          max_returned_at: self.get('maxReturnedAt'),
          price: item.get('price')
        });

        record.get('details').then(function(selectedRecord) {
          selectedRecord.pushObject( transactionDetail );
        });
      });

      record.save().then( function() {
          self.get('controllers.transactions.model').pushObject({});
          self.clearForm();
          self.transitionToRoute('transactions');
      });
    },

    goBack: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('transactions');
    },
  }
});
```

If I do create record, I got an error like this.

Error: Assertion Failed: The content property of DS.PromiseArray should be set before modifying it
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:26712:23)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:16896:15)
    at EmberObject.extend._replace (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:45514:15)
    at EmberObject.extend._insertAt (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:45529:14)
    at EmberObject.extend.pushObject (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:45573:14)
    at apply (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:31554:27)
    at superWrapper [as pushObject] (http://machine.dev:4200/assets/vendor.js:31132:15)
    at eval (pw-store/controllers/transactions/create.js:74:35)
    at Array.forEach (native) vendor.js:27637logToConsole vendor.js:27637RSVP.onerrorDefault vendor.js:41089__exports__.default.trigger vendor.js:59652Promise._onerror vendor.js:60651publishRejection vendor.js:58914(anonymous function) vendor.js:42243DeferredActionQueues.invoke vendor.js:13808DeferredActionQueues.flush vendor.js:13858Backburner.end vendor.js:13321Backburner.run vendor.js:13376apply vendor.js:31557run vendor.js:30173__exports__.default.EmberObject.extend._bubbleEvent vendor.js:50350(anonymous function) vendor.js:50298jQuery.event.dispatch vendor.js:4759jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle vendor.js:4427
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The content property of DS.PromiseArray should be set before modifying it

**UPDATE**

I have update my Ember Data to 1.0.0-beta.11 as suggested by Kingpin2k, but I got undefined error (see my comment below). I guess I do mistake on model and/or serializer but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: Upgrade Ember Data, setting async properties is a known issue with Ember Data pre 1.0 beta 12 (beta 11 solves creation with async properties).  Why are your models set as async and embedded?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll update my ember-data and give the report later. I set my models as async and embedded because I use SailsJS + sails-generate-ember-blueprints as backend where I set `ember: { sideload : true }` on sails config. If I don't set both async and embedded on Ember model, I'll got error. Am I do something wrong?

Comment: I got error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` after I update to Ember data 1.0.0-beta.11. After I inspect on Chrome Developer Tool, the error caused by `json[key] = embeddedRecord.serialize({includeId: true});`